# How to split a string into an array before a certain substring not after?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have a long string that contains many instances of the substring "trackButtonEvent(", I would like to split the array before the instance of this substring and not afterwards.

Example:

const contents: string = "Here is a file that has multiple instances of the trackButtonEvent(...); and here is another one trackButtonEvent(...); and now here is another occurrence trackButtonEvent(...); this is the end of the file.";

```
const contentArray: string[] = contents.split("trackButtonEvent(");

console.log("contentArray --> ", contentArray)

// Desired Results
['Here is a file that has multiple instances of the ', 'trackButtonEvent(...); and here is another one ', 'trackButtonEvent(...); and now here is another occurrence ', 'trackButtonEvent(...); this is the end of the file.']

// Actual Results
['Here is a file that has multiple instances of the ', '...); and here is another one ', '...); and now here is another occurrence ', '...); this is the end of the file.']
```

If I can split the string into an array before the occurrence of a particular word/string instead of afterwards, then I can loop through the array and make a new array of every occurrence of "trackButtonEvent(...);". This would be done by looping through the array and making a new array of the substring of between start= "trackButtonEvent(" and end ");"

```
function grabAnalyticStats(contents, nameOfAnalytic, start, end) {
  const exists = contents.includes(nameOfAnalytic);
  let itemString = '';
  if (exists) {
    const item = getStringInBetween(contents, start, end);
    itemString = start + item + end;
  }
  return itemString;
}
```

Ultimately, my goal is to have an array that looks like this: (

```
['trackButtonEvent(...some code #1);', 'trackButtonEvent(...some code #2);', 'trackButtonEvent(...some code #3);'];
```

If there is an alternative way to solve for the desired results without splitting before a word then looping through array to find substring between "trackButtonEvent(" and ");" then please let me know! Thank you!

Comment: If the contents of `...some code #2` can be *any valid JavaScript* (or some other programming language), then a trustworthy general-purpose solution would require a proper parser. Basic string manipulation could work for most cases, but getting the edge cases right will take quite some effort. You'd need to convert the string to a token tree, then locate `trackButtonEvent` calls, then recursively join the tree below that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to get all occurrences of a specific pattern.

```js
const contents = "Here is a file that has multiple instances of the trackButtonEvent(...); and here is another one trackButtonEvent(...); and now here is another occurrence trackButtonEvent(...); this is the end of the file.";
let res = contents.match(/trackButtonEvent\(.*?\);/g);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Oh wow thank you and how can we write this dynamically?

function searchAllContent(contents, nameOfAnalytic, start, end, search) {
  return contents.match(/`${nameOfAnalytic}`\(.*?\);/g);
}
^^ This doesn't seem to work

Comment: @Crystal Use `new RegExp('pattern', 'g')`. Note that you may need to escape regular expression metacharacters.

Comment: This fails if there are embedded functions, such as `trackButtonEvent( otherStuff(...); );`. It also fails if there are newlines.

Comment: @PeterThoeny Semicolons aren't valid inside an expression, but I'll update if the question specifies that requirement.

Comment: @Unmitigated: The OP statec `trackButtonEvent(...some code #1);`, so that code could be anything, and may include newlines

Comment: @PeterThoeny It depends on if it is actual JavaScript (or similar) code.

Comment: The trackButtonEvent function takes the same arguments every time so this solution does work for that (no semi colons within the (...)

Comment: @Unmitigated - I can't seem to get a function where the regular express works dynamically. Could you please help me by adding it to your answer? I will then select it officially as the answer. If I need to update the question - I can do that too. So I would like to have a function that returns contents.match(/nameOfAnalytics\(.*?\);/g); where nameOfAnalytics is dynamic

Comment: @Crystal `.match(new RegExp('nameOfAnalytics' + '\\(.*?\\);', 'g'))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a positive lookahead to do the split:

```js
const input = "Here is a file that has multiple instances of the trackButtonEvent(...); and here is another one trackButtonEvent(...); and now here is another occurrence trackButtonEvent(...); this is the end of the file.";
const regex = /(?=trackButtonEvent\()/;
const result = input.split(regex);
console.log(result);
```

Output:

```
[
  "Here is a file that has multiple instances of the ",
  "trackButtonEvent(...); and here is another one ",
  "trackButtonEvent(...); and now here is another occurrence ",
  "trackButtonEvent(...); this is the end of the file."
]
```

**UPDATE 1** based on additional filtering requirement:

```js
const input = "Here is a file that has multiple instances of the trackButtonEvent(...); and here is another one trackButtonEvent( withStuff(...); ); and now here is another occurrence trackButtonEvent(...); this is the end of the file.";
const regex = /(?=trackButtonEvent\()/;
const result = input
  .split(regex)
  .filter(str => regex.test(str))
  .map(str => str.replace(/^([\s\S]*\);).*/, '$1'));
console.log(result);
```

Output:

```
[
  "trackButtonEvent(...);",
  "trackButtonEvent( withStuff(...); );",
  "trackButtonEvent(...);"
]
```

Note that this fails if stuff **between** `trackButtonEvent(...);` contains `);`. If you have arbitrary code in between you need a proper language parser that builds a tree, so that you can pair opening and closing brackets. There is also a regex solution to pair parenthesis properly by nesting level, ask if interested.

**UPDATE 2** based on additional requirement to have a dynamic regex:

```js
const input = "Here is a file that has multiple instances of the trackButtonEvent(...); and here is another one trackButtonEvent( withStuff(...); ); and now here is another occurrence trackButtonEvent(...); this is the end of the file.";
const funcName = 'trackButtonEvent';
const regex = new RegExp('(?=' + funcName + '\\()');
const result = input
  .split(regex)
  .filter(str => regex.test(str))
  .map(str => str.replace(/^([\s\S]*\);).*/, '$1'));
console.log(result);
```

***Learn more about regex:*** https://twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/Codev/TWikiPresentation2018x10x14Regex

Comment: How can I make the ``trackButtonEvent`` dynamic within the reg expression?

Comment: @Crystal: See UPDATE 2

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this solution by using [`String.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method with the help of `RegEx`.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const str = "Here is a file that has multiple instances of the trackButtonEvent(...); and here is another one trackButtonEvent(...); and now here is another occurrence trackButtonEvent(...); this is the end of the file.";

const regExp = /trackButtonEvent\(([^)]+)\)/g;
const matches = [...str.match(regExp)];
console.log(matches)
```

`RegEx` explanation **:**

```
\( - matches a `(` char <br>
([^()]+) - Capturing group 1: a negated character class matching any 1 or more chars other than `(` and `)`<br>
\) - matches a `)` char.
```